# Android Location permissions code does not work correctly

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, geocoding

I wrote a simple code for getting Location permission from user at run time. **Only for the first time it worked correctly.** After that permission dialog box does not appear at all. Can any body tell me what is missing in the code...

```
  public static final String FINE_LOCATION=Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    public static final String COARSE_LOCATION=Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE=1234;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted=false;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        getLocationPermission();
}
    public void initMap() {

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 public void getLocationPermission(){
        String [] permissions={Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),COARSE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionGranted=true;
                initMap();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
             }
            }
            else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted=false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length>0){
                    for(int i=0;i<grantResults.length;i++){
                        if(grantResults[i]!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionGranted=false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    mLocationPermissionGranted=true;
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The gradle dependencies are given below:

```
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

I am new to google maps coding so I know less about it. Any body have a solution help me please. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
public static double longitude = 0.0d;
public static double latitude = 0.0d;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 30 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */
```

---

in oncreate you add this code :

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    // Create LocationSettingsRequest object using location request
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

    // Check whether location settings are satisfied
    // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient
    SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){

        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();

    } 
        return;
    else {


        // new Google API SDK v11 uses getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        // do work here
                        onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                    }
                },
                Looper.myLooper());

    }
}
```

Comment: public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // New location has now been determined
        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        latitude =location.getLatitude() ;
        longitude = location.getLongitude() ;
    }

Comment: private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {      Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);      }

Answer (score 3):

> Only for the first time it worked correctly. After that permission
>   dialog box does not appear at all

Once the permission is granted then there is no need to allow it again unless user change it via settings app or reinstall the app etc